# hybrid app slow document.hash everts?

Tags: javascript, performance, hybrid-mobile-app

So I know this is a shot in the dark but I thought I would ask.

I have a hybrid app that uses a light weight zepto page transition plugin, I currently have this set to not animate but simply load the page via ajax and push it into the dom  ( this is a single page app )

Everything for the most part works just fine but I have started to run into a little bottleneck with some longer lists ( nothing too huge, maybe 250 items )

Basically what I am seeing is that when I call the 'location.hash' line in my click event ( on touchend ) everything is running fast up until the point I call location.hash ( this triggers the page transition ) and will clock in at like 300 MS, now thats not horrible but what I get in the console seems to be shorter then what I see on the screen, I see somthing like 1 - 2 seconds before the page goes so like 2 to 4 times slower on the screen then what is in the console?

Anyhow this only seems to happen when the list is like over 100 objects that is whats strange.

Anyhow, like I said a shot in the dark but I am at a loss right now and any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The time lag could be due the number of click event registered on the DOM as the number of objects in the list increase. A possible solution would be to associate a single click event on the whole list and then based on the target returned in the click listener you can do the appropriate action.

I would also be helpful if you could create a JSFiddle page of the same so that we can check it out too.